# How to find confidence interval for a percentage and a mean difference in R?

Tags: r

```
t.test(Group.1 ~ Group.2, data=df1, conf.level=.90)
grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels
```

Columns are: category, Group.1, Group.2, Diff

Each row is a pair of samples for that category.

Lets say the 90% confidence interval.

Sample table:

```
category  Group.1  Group.2  Diff
1  0.4  0.6  -0.2
2  0.5  0.6  -0.1
3  0.7  0.5  0.2
```

Comment: you have an error: `grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels`

Comment: it means your group.2 has more than two unique values, the formula should be a numeric variable, like weight, `~` some grouping variable with two levels, like male/female

Comment: I added some sample data to the question.

Comment: Your data should have two columns, one with values and one with group membership. In your case: `df1=data.frame(category=rep(c("Group.1","Group.2"), each=3), values=c(0.4,0.5,0.7,0.6,0.6,0.5))`. Then your t.test is: `t.test(values ~ category, data=df1, conf.level=.90)`.

Comment: I can't work with the table I currently have? I have to use `data.frame()` and rewrite it all? My actual data is 10x the length.

Comment: You don't have to do it by hand. You can use, for example, the `melt` function from the `reshape2` package. With your data, `df1.melted = melt(df1, id.var="category")`.

Comment: `t.test(df1$Group.1, df1$Group.2, conf.level = 0.90)` if you are looking at not-matched data, `t.test(df1$Diff, conf.level = 0.90)` if matched?

Comment: there exist base functions which do not require add-on packages for a single function: `stack(df1[, c('Group.1','Group.2')])`